# Why am I getting array out of bounds with systemprefs?

Tags: android, arrays, system-preferences

my I am getting bug reports on Google Play that my app has had:

```
java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: length=0; index=9
    at punjokes.tuxstudios.com.punjokes.Pun.init(Pun.java:590)
    at punjokes.tuxstudios.com.punjokes.Pun.onCreateOptionsMenu(Pun.java:115)
```

I am trying to debug the app, but I am not getting the bug in Android Studio. Is there something I am missing? Thanks. I think it has something to do with the favorites. I have a list of puns and an option for the user to bookmark their favorite.

```
public class Pun extends AppCompatActivity {

    private InterstitialAd interstitial;

    public static final String mPath = "body.txt";
    public static final String mBusinessPath = "business.txt";
    public static final String mCrimePath = "crime.txt";
    public static final String mEducationPath = "education.txt";
    public static final String mEntertaintmentPath = "entertainment.txt";
    public static final String mFoodPath = "food.txt";
    public static final String mHealthPath = "health.txt";
    public static final String mNaturePath = "nature.txt";
    public static final String mPeoplePath = "people.txt";
    public static final String mPlacesPath = "places.txt";
    public static final String mTechnologyPath = "technology.txt";
    public static final String mTransportationPath = "transportation.txt";
    public static final String mWorkPath = "work.txt";
    private QuoteBank mQuoteBank;
    private List<String> mLines;
    private int counter = 0;
    private static int SIZE = 24;
    private String favorites1[] = new String[SIZE];
    private String favorites2[] = new String[SIZE];
    private String favorites3[] = new String[SIZE];
    private String favorites4[] = new String[SIZE];
    private String favorites5[] = new String[SIZE];
    private String favorites6[] = new String[SIZE];
    private String favorites7[] = new String[SIZE];
    private String favorites8[] = new String[SIZE];
    private String favorites9[] = new String[SIZE];
    private String favorites10[] = new String[SIZE];
    private String favorites11[] = new String[SIZE];
    private String favorites12[] = new String[SIZE];
    private String favorites13[] = new String[SIZE];

    public MenuItem star;

    public static int i1, i2;

    private ShareActionProvider shareAction;

    private TextView textView;
    private boolean listedPuns[] = new boolean[SIZE];
    private ArrayList<Integer> punShuffle;
    private int counter2 = 0;
    private int counter3 = 0;


    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.pun, menu);
        star = menu.findItem(R.id.action_favoritestar);
        init();

        MenuItem shareItem = menu.findItem(R.id.menu_item_share);

        shareAction = (ShareActionProvider) MenuItemCompat.getActionProvider(shareItem);

        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
        intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
        intent.setType("text/plain");
        intent.putExtra(intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "\"" + mLines.get(i1) + "\"\n\nSent from Pun Jokes: Funny Puns by Tux Studios\nhttps://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=punjokes.tuxstudios.com.punjokes&hl=en");

        shareAction.setShareIntent(intent);

        return true;
    }



    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.pun);


        Toolbar myToolbar3 = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.my_toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(myToolbar3);


        for (int i2 = 0; i2 < SIZE - 1; i2++) {
            listedPuns[i2] = false;
        }

        // Create the interstitial.
        interstitial = new InterstitialAd(this);
        interstitial.setAdUnitId("ca-app-pub-9704824959875003/5950200773");

        interstitial.setAdListener(new AdListener() {
            @Override
            public void onAdClosed() {
                requestNewInterstitial();
            }
        });

        requestNewInterstitial();

        mQuoteBank = new QuoteBank(this);

        textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView);


        Random r = new Random();
        i1 = r.nextInt(SIZE);

        mQuoteBank = new QuoteBank(this);
        mLines = mQuoteBank.readLine(mPath);

        textView.setText(mLines.get(i1));

        favorites1 = new String[SIZE];
        favorites2 = new String[SIZE];
        favorites3 = new String[SIZE];
        favorites4 = new String[SIZE];
        favorites5 = new String[SIZE];
        favorites6 = new String[SIZE];
        favorites7 = new String[SIZE];
        favorites8 = new String[SIZE];
        favorites9 = new String[SIZE];
        favorites10 = new String[SIZE];
        favorites11 = new String[SIZE];
        favorites12 = new String[SIZE];
        favorites13 = new String[SIZE];

        // Save and Load array
        favorites1 = loadArray("favorites1", this);
        favorites2 = loadArray("favorites2", this);
        favorites3 = loadArray("favorites3", this);
        favorites4 = loadArray("favorites4", this);
        favorites5 = loadArray("favorites5", this);
        favorites6 = loadArray("favorites6", this);
        favorites7 = loadArray("favorites7", this);
        favorites8 = loadArray("favorites8", this);
        favorites9 = loadArray("favorites9", this);
        favorites10 = loadArray("favorites10", this);
        favorites11 = loadArray("favorites11", this);
        favorites12 = loadArray("favorites12", this);
        favorites13 = loadArray("favorites13", this);



        final Button btn1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.next);
        btn1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                                    public void onClick(View v) {
                                        star.setIcon(R.drawable.starblank);

                                        i1 = randomExcluded();

                                        textView.setText(mLines.get(i1));
                                        invalidateOptionsMenu();
                                        counter++;

                                        counter3++;

                                        if (counter == 3) {
                                            Random r2 = new Random();
                                            i2 = r2.nextInt(11) + 1;

                                            Log.d("i2", "" + i2);
                                            counter = 0;

                                            if (i2 > 5) {
                                                if (interstitial.isLoaded())
                                                    interstitial.show();
                                            }
                                        }

                                        if(counter3 == 10){
                                            Random r2 = new Random();
                                            i2 = r2.nextInt(11) + 1;

                                            counter = 0;

                                        }


                                        switch (MainActivity.category) {
                                            case "body":
                                                if (favorites1[i1].equals("true")) {
                                                    star.setIcon(R.drawable.staryellow);
                                                } else {
                                                    star.setIcon(R.drawable.starblank);
                                                }
                                                break;
                                            case "crime":
                                                if (favorites2[i1].equals("true")) {
                                                    star.setIcon(R.drawable.starblank);
                                                } else {
                                                    star.setIcon(R.drawable.staryellow);
                                                }
                                                break;
                                            case "entertainment":
                                                if (favorites3[i1].equals("true")) {
                                                    star.setIcon(R.drawable.staryellow);
                                                } else {
                                                    star.setIcon(R.drawable.starblank);
                                                }
                                                break;
                                            case "health":
                                                if (favorites4[i1].equals("true")) {
                                                    star.setIcon(R.drawable.staryellow);
                                                } else {
                                                    star.setIcon(R.drawable.starblank);
                                                }
                                                break;
                                            case "people":
                                                if (favorites5[i1].equals("true")) {
                                                    star.setIcon(R.drawable.staryellow);
                                                } else {
                                                    star.setIcon(R.drawable.starblank);
                                                }
                                                break;
                                            case "technology":
                                                if (favorites6[i1].equals("true")) {
                                                    star.setIcon(R.drawable.staryellow);
                                                } else {
                                                    star.setIcon(R.drawable.starblank);
                                                }
                                                break;
                                            case "work":
                                                if (favorites7[i1].equals("true")) {
                                                    star.setIcon(R.drawable.staryellow);
                                                } else {
                                                    star.setIcon(R.drawable.starblank);
                                                }
                                                break;
                                            case "business":
                                                if (favorites8[i1].equals("true")) {
                                                    star.setIcon(R.drawable.staryellow);
                                                } else {
                                                    star.setIcon(R.drawable.starblank);
                                                }
                                                break;
                                            case "education":
                                                if (favorites9[i1].equals("true")) {
                                                    star.setIcon(R.drawable.staryellow);
                                                } else {
                                                    star.setIcon(R.drawable.starblank);
                                                }
                                                break;
                                            case "food":
                                                if (favorites10[i1].equals("true")) {
                                                    star.setIcon(R.drawable.staryellow);
                                                } else {
                                                    star.setIcon(R.drawable.starblank);
                                                }
                                                break;
                                            case "nature":
                                                if (favorites11[i1].equals("true")) {
                                                    star.setIcon(R.drawable.staryellow);
                                                } else {
                                                    star.setIcon(R.drawable.starblank);
                                                }
                                                break;
                                            case "places":
                                                if (favorites12[i1].equals("true")) {
                                                    star.setIcon(R.drawable.staryellow);
                                                } else {
                                                    star.setIcon(R.drawable.starblank);
                                                }
                                                break;
                                            case "transportation":
                                                if (favorites13[i1].equals("true")) {
                                                    star.setIcon(R.drawable.staryellow);
                                                } else {
                                                    star.setIcon(R.drawable.starblank);
                                                }
                                                break;
                                            default:
                                                break;
                                        }

                                        saveArray(favorites1, "favorites1", Pun.this);
                                        saveArray(favorites2, "favorites2", Pun.this);
                                        saveArray(favorites3, "favorites3", Pun.this);
                                        saveArray(favorites4, "favorites4", Pun.this);
                                        saveArray(favorites5, "favorites5", Pun.this);
                                        saveArray(favorites6, "favorites6", Pun.this);
                                        saveArray(favorites7, "favorites7", Pun.this);
                                        saveArray(favorites8, "favorites8", Pun.this);
                                        saveArray(favorites9, "favorites9", Pun.this);
                                        saveArray(favorites10, "favorites10", Pun.this);
                                        saveArray(favorites11, "favorites11", Pun.this);
                                        saveArray(favorites12, "favorites12", Pun.this);
                                        saveArray(favorites13, "favorites13", Pun.this);
                                    }
                                }

        );


    }


    private void requestNewInterstitial() {
        AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder()
                .build();

        interstitial.loadAd(adRequest);
    }

    public boolean saveArray(String[] array, String arrayName, Context mContext) {
        SharedPreferences prefs = mContext.getSharedPreferences("preferencename", 0);
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = prefs.edit();
        editor.putInt(arrayName + "_size", array.length);
        for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++)
            editor.putString(arrayName + "_" + i, array[i]);


        return editor.commit();
    }

    public String[] loadArray(String arrayName, Context mContext) {
        SharedPreferences prefs = mContext.getSharedPreferences("preferencename", 0);
        int size = prefs.getInt(arrayName + "_size", 0);
        String array[] = new String[size];
        for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
            array[i] = prefs.getString(arrayName + "_" + i, null);
            //if (array[i] == null)
        }
        return array;
    }


    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

        switch (item.getItemId()) {

            case R.id.about:
                // User chose the "Favorite" action, mark the current item
                // as a favorite...
                final Intent intent = new Intent(Pun.this, About.class);
                startActivity(intent);

                return true;

            case R.id.upgrade:
                alertDialog();
                return true;


            case R.id.submit:
                // User chose the "Favorite" action, mark the current item
                // as a favorite...
                final Intent intent1 = new Intent(Pun.this, Submit.class);
                startActivity(intent1);
                return true;

            case R.id.action_favorite:
                final Intent intent2 = new Intent(Pun.this, Favorites.class);
                startActivity(intent2);

                return true;

            case R.id.action_favoritestar:

                switch (MainActivity.category) {
                    case "body":
                        if (favorites1[i1].equals("true")) {
                            favorites1[i1] = "false";
                            star.setIcon(R.drawable.starblank);
                        } else {
                            favorites1[i1] = "true";
                            star.setIcon(R.drawable.staryellow);
                        }

                        Log.d("myTag", " " + favorites1[i1]);
                        break;
                    case "crime":
                        if (favorites2[i1].equals("true")) {
                            favorites2[i1] = "false";
                            star.setIcon(R.drawable.starblank);
                        } else {
                            favorites2[i1] = "true";
                            star.setIcon(R.drawable.staryellow);
                        }

                        Log.d("myTag", " " + favorites2[i1]);
                        break;
                    case "entertainment":
                        if (favorites3[i1].equals("true")) {
                            favorites3[i1] = "false";
                            star.setIcon(R.drawable.starblank);
                        } else {
                            favorites3[i1] = "true";
                            star.setIcon(R.drawable.staryellow);
                        }
                        break;
                    case "health":
                        if (favorites4[i1].equals("true")) {
                            favorites4[i1] = "false";
                            star.setIcon(R.drawable.starblank);
                        } else {
                            favorites4[i1] = "true";
                            star.setIcon(R.drawable.staryellow);
                        }
                        break;
                    case "people":
                        if (favorites5[i1].equals("true")) {
                            favorites5[i1] = "false";
                            star.setIcon(R.drawable.starblank);
                        } else {
                            favorites5[i1] = "true";
                            star.setIcon(R.drawable.staryellow);
                        }
                        break;
                    case "technology":
                        if (favorites6[i1].equals("true")) {
                            favorites6[i1] = "false";
                            star.setIcon(R.drawable.starblank);
                        } else {
                            favorites6[i1] = "true";
                            star.setIcon(R.drawable.staryellow);
                        }
                        break;
                    case "work":
                        if (favorites7[i1].equals("true")) {
                            favorites7[i1] = "false";
                            star.setIcon(R.drawable.starblank);
                        } else {
                            favorites7[i1] = "true";
                            star.setIcon(R.drawable.staryellow);
                        }
                        break;
                    case "business":
                        if (favorites8[i1].equals("true")) {
                            favorites8[i1] = "false";
                            star.setIcon(R.drawable.starblank);
                        } else {
                            favorites8[i1] = "true";
                            star.setIcon(R.drawable.staryellow);
                        }
                        break;
                    case "education":
                        if (favorites9[i1].equals("true")) {
                            favorites9[i1] = "false";
                            star.setIcon(R.drawable.starblank);
                        } else {
                            favorites9[i1] = "true";
                            star.setIcon(R.drawable.staryellow);
                        }
                        break;
                    case "food":
                        if (favorites10[i1].equals("true")) {
                            favorites10[i1] = "false";
                            star.setIcon(R.drawable.starblank);
                        } else {
                            favorites10[i1] = "true";
                            star.setIcon(R.drawable.staryellow);
                        }
                        break;
                    case "nature":
                        if (favorites11[i1].equals("true")) {
                            favorites11[i1] = "false";
                            star.setIcon(R.drawable.starblank);
                        } else {
                            favorites11[i1] = "true";
                            star.setIcon(R.drawable.staryellow);
                        }
                        break;
                    case "places":
                        if (favorites12[i1].equals("true")) {
                            favorites12[i1] = "false";
                            star.setIcon(R.drawable.starblank);
                        } else {
                            favorites12[i1] = "true";
                            star.setIcon(R.drawable.staryellow);
                        }
                        break;
                    case "transportation":
                        if (favorites13[i1].equals("true")) {
                            favorites13[i1] = "false";
                            star.setIcon(R.drawable.starblank);
                        } else {
                            favorites13[i1] = "true";
                            star.setIcon(R.drawable.staryellow);
                        }
                        Log.d("myTag", " " + favorites13[i1]);
                        break;
                    default:
                        break;



                }


                saveArray(favorites1, "favorites1", Pun.this);
                saveArray(favorites2, "favorites2", Pun.this);
                saveArray(favorites3, "favorites3", Pun.this);
                saveArray(favorites4, "favorites4", Pun.this);
                saveArray(favorites5, "favorites5", Pun.this);
                saveArray(favorites6, "favorites6", Pun.this);
                saveArray(favorites7, "favorites7", Pun.this);
                saveArray(favorites8, "favorites8", Pun.this);
                saveArray(favorites9, "favorites9", Pun.this);
                saveArray(favorites10, "favorites10", Pun.this);
                saveArray(favorites11, "favorites12", Pun.this);
                saveArray(favorites12, "favorites13", Pun.this);
                saveArray(favorites13, "favorites13", Pun.this);

                return true;

            case R.id.menu_item_share:


                return true;

            default:
                // If we got here, the user's action was not recognized.
                // Invoke the superclass to handle it.
                return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);

        }
    }

    public void init() {
        Log.d("myTag", " " + i1);

        switch (MainActivity.category) {
            case "body":
                mQuoteBank = new QuoteBank(this);
                mLines = mQuoteBank.readLine(mPath);


                if (favorites1[i1].equals("true"))
                    star.setIcon(R.drawable.staryellow);
                break;
            //[...] same as above but for favorites2, 3, etc.
        }
    }

    public int randomExcluded() {
        if(counter2 == 0){
            counter2++;
            punShuffle = new ArrayList<>();
            for (int i = 1; i <= SIZE; ++i) punShuffle.add(i);
            Collections.shuffle(punShuffle);
        }else if(counter2 == SIZE-1) {
            counter2 = 0;
        } else{
            counter2++;
        }

        Log.d("counter", "" + counter2);

        return punShuffle.get(counter2) - 1;

    }




}
```

Comment: `length=0; index=9` Your array is **empty**. But you are trying to address its 10th item.

Comment: Is it because the array is null if not true at specified location?

Comment: Would the solution be to make every element false if null?

Comment: you can try reading this for more info http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40006317/what-is-indexoutofboundsexception-how-can-i-fix-it/40006381#40006381

Comment: I tried if(favorites1!=null && favorites1.length==SIZE){ } ... but still crashes