# java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 11, Size: 11

Tags: indexoutofboundsexception

I am trying to execute a java method solve(String s) which takes the string and returns the biggest number present in the string. (The string contains letters and numbers). Whenever I try to run the code it throws an error - java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 11, Size: 11
This is my code:

```
    public ArrayList<Integer> getIntArray(ArrayList<String> stringArray) {
      ArrayList<Integer> result = new ArrayList<Integer>();
      for(String stringVal : stringArray) {
         result.add(Integer.parseInt(stringVal));  
      }
      return result;
   } 
   
   public int solve(String s) {
      StringBuilder str = new StringBuilder(s);
      ArrayList<String> arr = new ArrayList<String>();
      String[] strArr = s.split("");
      for(int i = 0; i < strArr.length; i++) {
         arr.add(strArr[i]);  
      }
      for(int i = 0; i < strArr.length; i++) {
         if(!Character.isLetter(i)) {
            arr.remove(i);   
         }
      }
      ArrayList<Integer> intArr = new ArrayList<Integer>();
      intArr = getIntArray(arr);
      return Collections.max(intArr);
```

Thanks. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is IndexOutOfBoundsException? How can I fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40006317/what-is-indexoutofboundsexception-how-can-i-fix-it)

Answer (score 0):

Most likely the problem is in the second for loop: in the loop stop condition you are checking the length of the `strArr` array, while inside the loop you are removing elements from the `arr` list.
BTW, there are several other problems with your code:

- iterating over a list and removing elements inside the loop is not a best idea (it won't work as you would expect) You could add condition to the first loop, or, even better, use streams.
- `Character.isLetter(i)` is always false, probably you meant `Character.isLetter(arr[i])`.