# String index out of range: 12 (Kotlin)

Tags: kotlin

I am trying to iterate through a string but it keeps throwing this error at 12.

```
fun main() {
    var testStr = "subject1EE/Physics - 101"

    for(i in 0..testStr.length){
        if (testStr[i].equals("/")) {
            testStr = testStr.dropLast(1)
            break
        } else {
            testStr = testStr.dropLast(1)
        }
    }

    println(testStr)
}
```

Error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: String index out of range: 12
    at java.base/java.lang.StringLatin1.charAt(StringLatin1.java:47)
    at java.base/java.lang.String.charAt(String.java:693)
    at com.example.jarnetor.TestKt.main(Test.kt:8)
    at com.example.jarnetor.TestKt.main(Test.kt)
```

Comment: You are sawing the branch you are sitting on. After 12 iterations, you have removed 12 characters from your string, and it is left with only 12 characters; `testStr[i]` is now beyond the end of the string. When iterating over a sequence you are deleting from, use `while` to control both the index and the length manually. Alternately, start from the tip of the branch (i.e. iterate from the end of the sequence to the front, as this does not mess up the indices you use later).

Comment: Why are you iterating through the string? What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is a StringIndexOutOfBoundsException? How can I fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40006317/what-is-a-stringindexoutofboundsexception-how-can-i-fix-it)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `for` loop will iterate from 0 up to the `testStr` length. But then inside the `for` loop, you are changing the `testStr` by dropping a character at a time. Of course, you will end up with an "index out of range" because your String is getting smaller but your `for` loop references its original length.

Assuming you want to get the substring before the slash, then you can simply do the following:

```kotlin
 fun main() {
    var testStr = "subject1EE/Physics - 101"

    println(testStr.substringBefore("/"))
}
```

Comment: Presumably, OP wants to get substring after the slash.

Comment: I guess it is the other way around. I believe OP wants to get the substring before the slash ;)