# How to use ternary operator with new?

Tags: java, ternary

I have this code:

```
if (providers.length > 0) 
        this.providers = providers;
    else 
        throw new IllegalArgumentException();
```

And i want to simplify it. I went for:

```
(providers.length > 0) ? this.providers = providers : throw new IllegalArgumentException();
```

But that gives me a compiler error. Why?

Comment: That is not "simplified", that is somewhat obfuscated and less readable.

Comment: The ternary operator syntax is `condition ? value1 : value2`. A `throw` statement is not a value. The ternary operator is not a universal shorthand for the `if` statement.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can Java's ternary/conditional operator (?:) be used to call methods instead of assigning values?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12554547/can-javas-ternary-conditional-operator-be-used-to-call-methods-instead-of)

Comment: The problem is that this is not seen as a *statement* by java. You can use ternary operators only in conjunction with an assignment. For example `int i = condition ? firstValue : secondValue;`.

Comment: @QBrute It is not true that the ternary operator can only be used in conjunction with assignment. However, it can only be used to evaluate a value, which is often the right hand side of an assignment.

Comment: @khelwood Ah yes, that's right. My bad.

Answer (score 4):

The reason why the ternary operator doesn't work is because that is for **assigning** values. Meaning: the "else" part after ":" needs to return a value of the same type as the "then" case after "?".

And `throw new` doesn't return a providers object ...

But in the end, that doesn't matter anyway; as the **really simple** version of that code looks more like:

```
if (providers.length == 0) {
    throw new IllegalArgumentException();
}

this.providers = providers;
```

And in order to make things easier to read, you could even go for:

```
checkProvidersNotEmpty(providers);
this.providers = providers;
```

In other words: you move the exception throwing into a separate method. The *implicit* convention here would be that a method named `checkSomething()` throws an exception when the check it does fails. And beyond that: give a reasonable message when creating that exception. It **will** help debugging later on.

You do not strive for the shortest program possible, but for the shortest version that comes with the best **reading** experience.

Using the ternary operator here would **not** result in an "easy to read" experience. Thus: forget about it.

Answer (score 0):

[Method Call using Ternary Operator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5490095/method-call-using-ternary-operator)

It's the same thing for Java, you have to return the same type of object.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can actually do this because the statement `throw new IllegalArgumentException()` cannot be assigned to `providers`.

From [Java documentation about Equality, Relational, and Conditional Operators](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/op2.html) :

> **The Conditional Operators**
>
> [...]
>   Another conditional operator is `?:`, which can be thought of as
>   shorthand for an `if-then-else` statement (discussed in the Control
>   Flow Statements section of this lesson). This operator is also known
>   as the ternary operator because it uses three operands. In the
>   following example, this operator should be read as: "If
>   `someCondition` is `true`, assign the value of `value1` to `result`.
>   Otherwise, assign the value of `value2` to `result`."

Answer (score -1):

You could do that too:

```
this.providers = providers.length > 0 ? providers : null;
if (this.providers == null)
    throw new IllegalArgumentException();
```

But normally You should let Your code in cases like that as it is.
That's in that case much better and less complicated.