# Java: HashMap containskey return value error

Tags: java, eclipse

i discovered a strange behavior in HashMap using Eclipse 4.7.2.

The following line seems correct for me:

```
infos.containsKey("desc") ? stmt.setString(8, infos.get("desc")) : 
stmt.setString(8, "No description");
```

`infos` is type of `HashMap<String, String>` and a `PreparedStatement` should be filled with the value of the description (`desc`) field in the map.

But instead of just doing what is written there Eclipse indicates that in this line are multiple errors:

```
 infos.containsKey**("desc")** ? stmt.setString(8, infos.get("desc")) :
 stmt.setString(8, "No description"**)**;
```

I marked the characters which are underlined in Eclipse.

The error message is:

```
Multiple markers at this line
    - Syntax error on token ")", delete this token
    - Syntax error, insert ")" to complete Expression
    - Type mismatch: cannot convert from String to 
     boolean
```

The function of the ? operater is rather clear but the behavior is unclear.

Does anyone can show me where I am wrong or how to aviod this error.

Thank you!

Comment: Why not `stmt.setString(8, infos.containsKey("desc") ? infos.get("desc") : "No description");`?

Comment: @EpicPandaForce thank you, in my comment I did it the same way :-D

Comment: The difference is that your latter ternary "returns" a string that's not assigned to any variable but which _could_ be assigned. Your original version would "return" `void` which can not be assigned and hence isn't supported. From the [JLS](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.25): `It is a compile-time error for either the second or the third operand expression to be an invocation of a void method.`

Comment: [Can Java's ternary/conditional operator (?:) be used to call methods instead of assigning values?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12554547)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Problem is that conditional operator `boolean ? value1 : value2` expects values but [`stmt.setString`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/sql/PreparedStatement.html#setString-int-java.lang.String-) returns `void` which represents lack of any value.

Simpler solution would be using [`Map#getOrDefault(key, defaultValue)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Map.html#getOrDefault-java.lang.Object-V-) provided in Java 8 like

```
stmt.setString(8, infos.getOrDefault("desc", "No description"));
```

Answer (score 1):

The `PreparedStatement.setString` method returns void.

The purpose of the ternary operator is to return one value or another. Therefore, you cannot use expressions returning void. Furthermore, both expressions must return a value of the same type.

As indicated elsewhere, you should use a traditional if ... else statement, or write it like this:

```
stmt.setString(8, infos.containsKey("desc") ? infos.get("desc") : "No description")
```

Answer (score 0):

Convert your code to traditional `if...else` instead of ternary operator

```
if(infos.containsKey("desc"))
   stmt.setString(8, infos.get("desc"));
else
   stmt.setString(8, "No description");
```

Answer (score 0):

It is a compile-time error in ternary operator  for either the second or the third operand expression to be an invocation of a void method. More you can read about it here

[java conditional operator](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.25)

you can use like this.

```
 String str = infos.containsKey("desc") ?  infos.get("desc") : "No description";
 stmt.setString(8, str);
```