# Why is it mandatory for ternary operations to return a value?

Tags: java, compilation, ternary-operator

I've read related questions and answers (for instance, [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12554547/can-javas-ternary-conditional-operator-be-used-to-call-methods-instead-of)). But they are about whether it's possible to use ternary operation without assignment. My question is ***why*** it isn't not supported in Java? Is there some fundamental reason related to compilation? Are there programming languages that support it?

The reason I'm asking is because a statement

```
<condition> ? <do this if true> : <do that if false>
```

isn't only more elegant and saves 4 lines of code, but also isn't much different from

```
value = <condition> ? <this if true> : <that if false>
```

Here is a practical example of an implementation of market data order book:

```
public class OrderBook {

    public TreeMap<Integer, Integer> bids = new TreeMap<>(Collections.reverseOrder());
    public TreeMap<Integer, Integer> asks = new TreeMap<>();

    public void quote(boolean isBid, int price, int size) {
        Map<Integer, Integer> book = isBid ? bids : asks;
        if (size == 0) {
            book.remove(price);
        } else {
            book.put(price, size);
        }
    }
}
```

And here is a *workaround*:

```
public void quote(boolean isBid, int price, int size) {
    Map<Integer, Integer> book = isBid ? bids : asks;
    @SuppressWarnings("unused")
    Integer sizePrevious = (size == 0) ? book.remove(price) : book.put(price, size);
}
```

But it would look more elegant just like this:

```
public void quote(boolean isBid, int price, int size) {
    Map<Integer, Integer> book = isBid ? bids : asks;
    (size == 0) ? book.remove(price) : book.put(price, size);
}
```

which isn't compiling of course.

Comment: It's just a choice, like thousands of other made during the creation of Java

Comment: Elegance is in the eye of the beholder.

Comment: [jls-15.25. Conditional Operator `? :`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.25) defines what the operator **must** do. If an implementation chose to do something else, it would not be Java. The link notes *In fact, by the grammar of expression statements ([§14.8](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-14.html#jls-14.8)), it is not permitted for a conditional expression to appear in any context where an invocation of a void method could appear.*

Comment: _Side effects_ can also be considered an anti-pattern, especially by functional-programming purists. One could also ask whether an _operation_ should return a value or not and how elegant _void_ methods actually are.

Comment: @MickMnemonic, isn't there always at some stage must be something that doesn't return anything? And it seems to be the purpose of all others which return something.

Answer (score 5):

It's a matter of [specification](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se11/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.25):

> The first expression must be of type boolean or Boolean, or a compile-time error occurs.
>
> It is a compile-time error for either the second or the third operand expression to be an invocation of a void method.

There's nothing stopping a *different* JVM language from handling `foo ? bar() : baz()` with bar and baz `null` as a conditional in the way you intend. Somewhat along these lines, Kotlin's [conditionals](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/control-flow.html) use the same structure for calling functions and returning values:

> ```
> val max = if (a > b) a else b
> ```

works just as well as

> ```
> if (a>b) a() else b()
> ```

The Kotlin language designers could have very easily chosen to use a conditional operator in the Java `a?b:c` style, but it's likely that this is considered to be more readable and expressive.

Answer (score 0):

This (which is not allowed):

```
<condition> ? <do this if true> : <do this if false>
```

can be written:

```
if (<condition>) { <do this if true> } else { <do this if false> }
```

isn't this more elegant and readable?

On the other hand this (which is allowed):

```
value = <condition> ? <this if true> : <that if false>
```

could be written:

```
if (<condition>) { value = <this if true>} else { value = <this if false>  }
```

you can choose whatever you like.

In Kotlin where there is no ternary operator you can use a much more elegant way:

```
value = if (<condition>) { <this if true>} else { <this if false>  }
```

Comment: Thanks for answering, but the workaround with `{}` isn't more elegant because it's a non conventional code style. And assigning the  value inside `{}` requires declaring it outside the if/else scope.

Comment: The brackets are not mandatory for simple statements like: `if (true)  value = 0; else value = 0;`

Comment: Right, we can write the entire code like this, but that is also unconventional code style.

Comment: Why do you find it unconventional? I personally prefer Kotlin's way where as I mentioned there is no ternary operator. But this is the way Java is structured.